# How do I test whether a Python SQL query worked if it's not supposed to return anything?

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

I read an excellent post here about error handling. [Error handling in Python-MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996401/error-handling-in-python-mysql)

And there are a thousand similar questions from people with problems where their query isn't returning anything - but that's because it's supposed to.

I have a slightly different problem.

I have a SQL Query which is designed to transform creating a new table.

```
SELECT *
INTO MyDataBase.MySchema.NewTable
FROM

    (SELECT
        ID,
        Count(*) AS ProductCount
    FROM
        MyDataBase.MySchema.MyTable
    GROUP BY 
        ID

    ) ProductCount
```

If I run the query in SSMS it works perfectly and SSMS simply tells me

```
(1901 rows affected)
Completion time: 2021-12-07T09:28:32.2541722+13:00
```

But after I deliberatly ***mis-edit*** the code, and try running the query from a pyhon script just gives me a vague result with no indicaton that the script didn;t actually work.

```
row = curs.fetchone()
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.
```

So... How do I check that the tranform, the SQL query, ran successfully, even if it's not supposed to return any results... from python?

I know it didn't.

Comment: Have you considered wrapping it in a `begin - end` block and also returning a success status

Comment: No.... success status?

Comment: The fact the the query didn't return an error means that the statements ran successfully...

Comment: "not throwing an error" does not always mean "worked". Careful what you assume and how you apply this concept.

Comment: @Lamu so you're saying invert the interpretation? Assume it worked unless told otherwise? Well that is exactkly what is happenign on another transform type query. The query actually failed in SSMS when I tried. but the python approach said nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`fetchone()` is to return rows if there are outputs. You don't need it in your case.

Any DDL statements you can run by just using `cursor.execute('drop table..')`. There is no way to know for sure if it worked actually, but if it didn't error out then it was successful. You can have additional checks to be sure based on scenario.

Also don't forget to do a `cursor.commit()` in the end, else it won't commit all your statements.

Comment: "There is no way to know for sure if it worked actually". That's exactly the problem. So the particular query I.m trying to run is quite long, and it actually didn;t work in SSMS. but when I run it from python, I get no feedback to say it didn't work.

So you're saying I have to then go do specific checks to see if the query had the desired effect?

Comment: Yes, you can try using TRANSACTION with TRY CATCH like in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146656/sql-try-catch-rollback-commit-preventing-erroneous-commit-after-rollback/25147092

Comment: I think we're talking at cross purposes. The article you pointed me to is dealing with the SQL script itself being the problem. That is not my scenario.